# Why is React useEffect() unmount not changing variable value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ionic-framework, error-handling, console.log

I'm creating a React app and now I'm building the authentication part. Every thing is working fine but when the user logs in I have to unmount my logging component and show the home page.

I'm using Ionic React to have already made components and to show the login I'm using `<IonModal />` component which has a swipeToClose prop.

So, when the user swipes to close the modal I'm listening to the `onWillDismiss` event to set the state variable `modalOpened` to `false`.

Every thing works great but since I'm unmounting my `<Auth/>` component when the user is logged in the modal `onWillDismiss` is triggered and it tries to update my state which doesn't exists because my component is unmounted.

I tried to create a boolean variable which is set to true when the event can update the state and false when the state can't be updated. I'm using `useEffect` hook to detect the component unmounting.
Strangely when my variable is set to `false` in my `useEffect` it is set back to true in my `onWillDismiss` event.

Here is my code:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {
    IonPage,
    IonContent,
    IonModal,
    IonSlides,
    IonSlide,
    IonButton,
} from "@ionic/react";
import Login from "./Login";

// *Stylesheet
import "./style.scss";
import { AuthSuccess } from "../../types";

const Auth: React.FC<AuthSuccess> = ({ onSuccess: successHandler }) => {
    const [modalOpened, openModal] = useState(false);
    let updateModal: boolean = true;

    useEffect(() => {
        return () => {
            updateModal = false;
            console.log("use effect update modal is", updateModal);
        };
    }, []);

    return (
        <IonPage>
            <IonContent>
                <div className="slideContainer">
                    <IonSlides pager className="slide">
                        <IonSlide>Welcome</IonSlide>
                        <IonSlide>First Step</IonSlide>
                        <IonSlide>Second Step</IonSlide>
                        <IonSlide>Third Step</IonSlide>
                    </IonSlides>
                    <IonButton
                        mode="ios"
                        className="login"
                        onClick={() => openModal(modalOpened ? false : true)}
                    >
                        Login
                    </IonButton>
                </div>
            </IonContent>
            <IonModal
                isOpen={modalOpened}
                swipeToClose
                onWillDismiss={() => {
                    console.log("on dismiss", updateModal);
                    return updateModal ? openModal(false) : null;
                }}
                mode="ios"
            >
                <Login onSuccess={successHandler} />
            </IonModal>
        </IonPage>
    );
};

export default Auth;
```

and here is a screen shot of my console

[image: The output in my console]

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found my solution thanks to VS Code eslint extansion.

> Assignments to the 'updateModal' variable from inside React Hook useEffect will be lost after each render. To preserve the value over time, store it in a useRef Hook and keep the mutable value in the '.current' property. Otherwise, you can move this variable directly inside useEffect.eslint(react-hooks/exhaustive-deps)

I used useRef hook and now everything works fine !